# How to get previous 7 days' data from today in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a DataEntry Table called `GuestAddressData(UserId INT, EDate DateTime)` with users data. I need to fetch the count of users for **today to previous 7 Days**. My Query:

```
SELECT 
  row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) ID,
  count(*) Total,
  LEFT(Datename(weekday, Cast(EDate as date)), 3) Day
FROM 
  CRM0001GuestAddressData
WHERE
  EDate >= dateadd(week, datediff(d, -1, getdate()-2)/7, -1)
GROUP BY
  Cast(EDate as date)
ORDER BY
  Cast(EDate as date)
```

For example if today is Friday then my expected output is:

```
ID   |   TOTAL  |   DAY
------------------------
1    |    78    |   Sat
2    |    23    |   Sun
3    |    54    |   Mon
4    |    17    |   Tues
5    |    56    |   Wed
6    |    45    |   Thus
7    |    78    |   Fri  -  Today
```

but this is not correct. How to solve it?

Comment: You need single quotes around the date constant.  If that is the only problem, then this is a simple typographical error.

Comment: `2018-09-25-2` is a math operation, with a result of `1982`.

Comment: @KenWhite replace 018-09-25 with getdate() please  018-09-25-2 is only testing data

Comment: I don't need  to replace anything. If you have a problem with code, you're supposed to be posting your actual code, and the code you posted had a math operation in that position. If it's not your real code in the post, then [edit] again and supply your actual problematic code.

Comment: where clause problem...   where EDate between dateadd(d,-7,cast(getdate() as date)) and getdate()

Comment: @KenWhite i have already edited please check and focus on your work without westing time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "generate" a list of seven numbers and use it to build the desired dates. Then left join with your data to get the counts, including zeros:

```
WITH datelist(num, a, b) AS (
    SELECT num, DATEADD(DAY, -num, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)), DATEADD(DAY, -num + 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) AS v(num)
)
SELECT 7 - num AS ID, datelist.a AS Day, COUNT(IDBooking)
FROM datelist
LEFT JOIN T_Bookings ON Opened >= datelist.a AND Opened < datelist.b
GROUP BY datelist.a, datelist.num
ORDER BY datelist.a
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is perfect for available all day entry, but in case , no data available in the  list of previous 7 days ...show count 0 or NULL of that day IS IT POSSIBLE?

Comment: I was worried you might ask that, wait.

Comment: @aparnarai, Oh you should have said from start, simply cross join with a tally of 7 days. I will edit.

Comment: @aparnarai see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  row_number() over (order by dDate) ID,
  cnt,
  LEFT(Datename(weekday, dDate), 3) Day
from
(Select cast(EDate as Date) as dDate,
       count(*) as cnt
FROM (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(v)
  inner join
  CRM0001GuestAddressData gd on datediff(d, gd.Edate, getdate()) = t.v 
WHERE
  EDate >= dateadd(d, -6, cast(getdate() as date)) and EDate < dateadd(d,1,cast(getdate() as date))
GROUP BY
  Cast(EDate as date)) tmp;
```

Note: You meant to get 7 days from yesterday, right? Nevermind, corrected based on your sample.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f602680a12efaf87691d86aa30fbd51c)

EDIT: Having all days:

```
SELECT 
  row_number() over (order by dDate) ID,
  cnt,
  LEFT(Datename(weekday, dDate), 3) Day
from
(Select dateadd(d,-v,cast(getdate() as date)) as dDate,
       count(Edate) as cnt
FROM (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(v)
  left join
  CRM0001GuestAddressData gd on Datediff(d,gd.EDate, getdate()) = t.v 
GROUP BY
  dateadd(d,-v,cast(getdate() as date))) tmp;
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34d05757a76faf39b0abe0f6aa07a688)

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is perfect for available all day entry, but in case , no data available in the  list of previous 7 days ...show count 0 or NULL of that day IS IT POSSIBLE?

Comment: @aparnarai, wish you said that from the start. Edited for that case.